FCM HTTP v1 API Subscribe to Topic Error - FIS_AUTH_ERROR
I want to subscribe users to a topic using FCM HTTP v1 API with java in Android studio and send PHP notifications based on this subscription. However, when I try to subscribe to the topic, I get the following error:
Failed to sync topics. Won't retry sync. java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR

google-services.json dosyasını en güncel haliyle indirip app klasörüne attım.
The code I used for the subscription is as follows (just below onCreate):
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("APP ID") // Required for Analytics.
    .setProjectId("PROJECT ID") // Required for Firebase Installations.
    .setApiKey("GOOGLE API KEY") // Required for Auth.
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "FIREBASE APP NAME");

I tried everything suggested but I couldn't get the subscription done. I've been working on this for a long time. I'd be very happy if you could help me. Thanks in advance.
